# Can I specify a alias for ActiveMQ server to pick an specify cert from keystore

Tags: ssl-certificate, activemq-classic, keystore

I have a keystore with multiples entry. ActiveMQ is picking the first certificate that it finds which is the wrong one. I am using version 5.17.1 and configuration is being done in the `activemq.xml` file:

```xml
<sslContext>
   <sslContext keyStore="file:${activemq.conf}/broker.ks"
               keyStorePassword="your_keystore_password" 
               trustStore="file:${activemq.conf}/broker.ks" 
               trustStorePassword="your_keystore_password" />
</sslContext>
```

Is there any way to provide the alias of the cert that server should pick.

Comment: @JustinBertram I am using version 5.17.1 and configuration is being done in the activemq.xml file 

<sslContext>
    <sslContext keyStore="file:${activemq.conf}/broker.ks"
                keyStorePassword="your_keystore_password"
                trustStore="file:${activemq.conf}/broker.ks"
                trustStorePassword="your_keystore_password" />
</sslContext>

Comment: I created JIRA https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMQ-9294 to add support for this. Currently, the broker reads in the first key (historically, the convention was one-key per keystore).

Comment: Thanks @MattPavlovich for opening that Jira, that will be really helpful